# MS Server 2012 - Adding New Classes to User, Computer, and Group Objects

Tags: active-directory, osx-mavericks

We are trying to get an AD server to work with an Apple OD server.  The AD server can talk to the OD server, but the OD Server is not able to talk to the AD server.  From what I've read it looks like the issue is due to the Apple Schema Attributes.  I have added all the attributes, but an at a standstill on that last part.  I can not figure out how to ass the new classes to the Objects.

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer by re-reading some guides I found online; namely the one here: http://www.macservice.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/WP_ActiveDirectory1.pdf

[image: Screenshot of the solution]